# Adding css to radio button for checked and clear css unchecked in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I style the radio button for checked only and clear it? I've tried several ways. It's not clearing.

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function () {
    var $field_type = $("[name=field]:checked");
    #and other field types doing the same thing
    $("label[for='" + $field_type.attr('id') + "']").css({'border': '2px solid #333'})
```

I also tried `$("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").css({'border': '2px solid #333'})`. It does the same thing.

Comment: Would you add the relevant HTML to your question?

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem here.

Comment: Use a class for styling and assign that using add/remove/toggle class. Separating your functional code from representation will make the whole thing easier to debug and manage going forward.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input:radio').on('click', function () {
  $('input[name="RD"]').next().css({'border': 'none'});
  $("label[for='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").css({'border': '2px solid #333'})
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="RD" id="RD1"/><label for="RD1">radio1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="RD" id="RD2"/><label for="RD2">radio2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to simply write a CSS selector that kicks in when the radio button is checked. **No JavaScript needed.**

But keep in mind that not all browsers allow radio buttons to be styled in any way you like. However, the label elements that go with them can be styled easily:

```css
/* This rule will only be appled when the radio button is selected. 
   but, not all browsers allow radio button styling.                */
input[type='radio']:checked {
  background-color:yellow;
}

/* This rule will affect the label that comes after the checked radio button: */
input[type='radio']:checked + label {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test" value="on"><label for="test">On</label>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test2" value="off"><label for="test2">Off</label>
```

**[Here's an interesting link](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/)** that shows how to customize the buttons and check marks easily.

Comment: yeah i tried this before posting too... it didn't work. Selected button doesn't get a css update.

Comment: @JamAndJammies As I said, most browsers won't let you style the actual radio button directly, but styling the label (as you are trying to do in your question) is easy and my code shows that working just fine. If you want to style the button itself, check out the link at the end of my answer.